# How to represent XML as pages of a form in HTML, transformed with XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to transform an XML file to HTML with XSLT 1.0. The structure of the output shall be presented like pages of a form. Depending on the amount of content in the XML file, multiple pages may be necessary. The header and footer of the form are to be the same on every page.

The middle section contains a table with data extracted from the XML. This section may contain at max 15 rows. If more would be needed, a new page is to be added. Additionally, it is possible that an entry row is double the size of a regular row (if the content is large enough to require it). This means, that if 14 rows are written and the next would be a double-sized row, a new page needs to be started. The check whether an entry needs two rows is done by simply counting the characters of the content. If a certain number is passed, a double row will be created. This also works already.

My question is, how to start a new page (which could be simply done in form of adding the footer and the header) when I need to? Creating the header, footer or the content table is not a problem, neither is accessing the data from the XML.

My first thought was to count up a counter variable in the for-each (on all content entries in the XML) and determine before each addition of a row whether a page is needed or not, but given that variables cannot really increment in XSL, I figured that this is a dead end.

My second thought was that I could count the number of content entries ahead, thus determining before building the pages, how many of them will be needed. However, here I run into a similar problem as before: while I could count simply all occurences, I do not see how I could take into account the fact that sometimes I need to count two rows for one entry.

Sadly I am for now pretty much stuck here. Is there something I have overlooked so far?

If needed, I can of course post areas of the code, but right at the moment I would not know which segments would be relevant. If requested, I will of course add whatever areas of code would be helpful.

Comment: So the target format is HTML and you expect the data to be presented as multiple "pages"? What do you consider a page with HTML? Are you using XSLT server-side or client-side? Do you use an XSLT 1.0 processor that implements an extension to create various result documents?

Comment: A "page" in this context means a predefined structure for a certain form. In reality it is a repeated sequence of a header, a middle table and a footer. I use client-side. The last question I do not entirely understand. The result is intended to be one single representation in a browser.